# C Initialize Struct with a loop

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Below I have the code for a struct in a program I'm writing. I would like to be able to initialize these parameters in some sort of loop, but I can't seem to figure out how to configure the `.water`/`.air`/`.purge` properties to update with the loop. `nozzle_count` is 16 so I would like to find a way to achieve the code below without having to just copy and paste it 16 times. I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!

```
static nozzle nozzles[nozzle_count] = {
    {
        .water = C1_WATER, .air = C1_AIR, .purge = C1_PURGE,
        .interval = 15*60*1000, .cycle = 0*3*5*1000, .purge_length = 0*4*1000,
        .state = WAIT
    },
    {
        .water = C2_WATER, .air = C2_AIR, .purge = C2_PURGE,
        .interval = 2*60*1000, .cycle = 1*3*1000, .purge_length = 0*4*1000,
        .state = WAIT
    },
    {
        .water = C3_WATER, .air = C3_AIR, .purge = C3_PURGE,
        .interval = 2*60*1000, .cycle = 0*1*5*1000, .purge_length = 0*4*1000,
        .state = WAIT
    }
    {
        .water = C4_WATER, .air = C4_AIR, .purge = C4_PURGE,
        .interval = 2*60*1000, .cycle = 0*1*5*1000, .purge_length = 0*4*1000,
        .state = WAIT
    }
    {
        .water = C5_WATER, .air = C5_AIR, .purge = C5_PURGE,
        .interval = 2*60*1000, .cycle = 0*1*5*1000, .purge_length = 0*4*1000,
        .state = WAIT
    }
};
```

Comment: I do not believe what you are seeking is possible.

Comment: It's conceivably possible in C++ with `constexpr` and/or template magic, but yeah, in C you'd be limited to truly terrible recursive macros, where the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: If some (or all) values are potentially different and irregular then there's no meaningful way to use a loop here. Why would you even want a loop? What would be the point?

Comment: `interval` and `cycle` appear to change.  Is that by accident?  If not, how do you derive those values?

Comment: Show the definitions of `C1_WATER`, `C1_AIR`, `C2_WATER` etc.

Comment: Also, what types do `water`, `air`, `purge` have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code looks perfectly fine, even if the length of your array is increased from 5 to 16. Two possible suggestions.

If you remove the C99 initialization fluff, then everything can fit into a single line:

```
static nozzle nozzles[nozzle_count] = {
//    water     air     purge     interval    cycle       purge_length state
//    --------  ------  --------  ----------  ----------  ------------ ----
    { C1_WATER, C1_AIR, C1_PURGE, 15*60*1000, 0*3*5*1000, 0*4*1000,    WAIT },
//  ...
};
```

This is a simple table, just 16 lines long, which is clear and obvious and which is easy-to-maintain.

Secondly, if you need to *keep* the per-member initialization, you could enclose it a macro, which helps with DRY:

```
#define FOO(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)                                 \
    {                                                            \
       .water = (a), .air = (b), .purge = (c),                   \
       .interval = (d), .cycle = (e),  .purge_length = (f),      \
       .state = (b)                                              \
    }

static nozzle nozzles[nozzle_count] = {
//    water     air     purge     interval    cycle       purge_length state
//    --------  ------  --------  ----------  ----------  ------------ ----
 FOO( C1_WATER, C1_AIR, C1_PURGE, 15*60*1000, 0*3*5*1000, 0*4*1000,    WAIT ),
//  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I can think of is:

```
const TYPE_OF_CxPURGE PURGE[] = {...};
const TYPE_OF_CxAIR AIR[] = {....};
const TYPE_OF_CxWATER WATER[] = {....};
```

And somewhere in the code

```
for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(nozzles) / sizeof(nozzles[0]); index ++)
{
    nozzles.water = WATER[index];
    nozzles.air = AIR[index]; 
    nozzles.purge = PURGE[index];
    nozzles.interval = 15*60*1000; 
    nozzles.cycle = 0*3*5*1000; 
    nozzles.purge_length = 0*4*1000,
    nozzles.state = WAIT
}
```

But I think that the normal initialization is better. Only 16 elements. If you have more just write the script to generate this initialization code

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the definition of `*_WATER`, `*_AIR`, `*_PURGE`?

```
for (i = 0; i < nozzle_count; i++)
{
    nozzles[i] = (struct nozzle){WATER[i], AIR[i], PURGE[i], 15*60*1000, 0, 0, WAIT};
}
```